# How can I reinstall Linux Mint so that my previous data doesn't get lost?

Tags: linux-mint

I had some problems with GRUB, so I was advised to reinstall Linux to solve it. But while doing so i don't want to lose all my previous data.

I have come till this:

[image: gparted]

What should I do next? As it is obvious my data is in ext4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to backup your userdata to another drive since you didn't make a separate /home partition, and you didn't set the mount points on your screenshot, one should be / and another should be /home.

Answer (score 0):

As Zulgrib said, in your case you would have to copy the home directory /home/username to a Pendrive or an external media and then you do your reinstall.

When the installation is done, you would have to copy your data back. Since you are reinstalling Mint, from Mint, there should be no issue with that.

I do recommend, that while doing a reinstall anyway, that you set up your partitioner like this:

partition a with mount point / 
partition b with mount point /home

The / one is usually fine with 50GB or so, since most data is stored in /home.

Using this setup, you will get two partitions with the home directory being on a separate one. If you would have to reinstall again, you would just format the / one and reinstall on it, while simply mounting /home as it is (without formatting). This way you usually do not even need a backup, though it might still be recommended to have one just in case.